# Saving XSL attributes to JavaScript array under condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, xslt

I am new to XSL and spent hours finding a solution to extract the attribute values from XSLT.

My XML looks like:

```
<itemList>
  <item id="1" name="mydoc1"  showItem="option1">My documents1</item>
  <item id="2" name="mydoc1"  showItem="option2">My documents2</item>
  <item id="2" name="mydoc1"  showItem="option1">My documents3</item>
  ...
  <item id="k" name="mydocWhatever"  showItem="option1">My documents Whatever</item>
  ...

  <item id="n" name="mydocN"  showItem="optionN">My documentsN</item>
</itemList>
```

I want to get all `item.name` when `showItem="option1"` and store it to JavaScript array or object.

I tried this but it does not work.

```
<xsl:for-each select="itemList/item[@showItem = 'option1']"> 
  myItem='<xsl:value-of select="//itemList/item/@name"/>');
</xsl:for-each>
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Your context changes inside the `<xsl:for-each>`, and since there are no descendant `<itemlist>`s, your selection is empty.

```
<xsl:for-each select="itemList/item[@showItem = 'option1']"> 
    myItem = '<xsl:value-of select="@name" />' ; 
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:text>var myItem = [</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each select="itemList/item[@showItem = 'option1']">
  <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">, </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat(&quot;'&quot;, @name, &quot;'&quot;)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:text>];</xsl:text>
```

should output `var myItem = ['mydoc1', 'mydoc1', 'mydocWhatever'];`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I tried the above, it's not working in my code.

I can get an array of all names by using the following:

    myItem='<xsl:value-of select="//itemList/item/@name"/>';

But after I add a condition, 

    myItem='<xsl:value-of select="//itemList/item[@showItem='option1']/@name"/>';

myItem is empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed, it's caused by the pre processor, the attribute "showItem" was filtered out. That's why I can not see it.